# getting wordID from a hash table of another machine in the same network

Tags: c++, linux, hashmap, cgi

i'm working on a search engine, it is composed of an apache server, a crawler, a lexicon, and an indexer, all these machines are on the same local network.

the apache server contains a cgi script that will retrive the query, parse it and the lexicon will convert the query into word ID using a hash map. the question is how can i get the lexicon to convert the query to word ID using the cgi script.

**in other words** : i want to get the wordID from the lexicon very quickly knowing that the lexicon is in another machine?

**EDIT:** how can i run another program from another program. of course without using SSH?

Comment: We have no idea how this setup actually works so it's difficult if not impossible to provide a solution.

Comment: i have a hash map in Machine 1, how can i access this hash map from Machine 2? any solution will be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

you've got to be more specific.

Your lexicon is a program ? a binary written hastable into a file? a quantic computeur used as lexicon ?

to communicate through a network you have many options, from writing a client / server with tcp/ip, even udp , or even layer 2 is enough , use a web server and a server side language to access server side data, even a shared folder can be used

well given the informations you provide. no answer could be done

Comment: yes the lexicon is a program, and after starting it will create a hash table from a file. now i need the cgi script to access this hash table.

Comment: _"well given the informations you provide. no answer could be done"_ - if a proper answer cannot be provided why is your post an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @captain obvlious, because I can't.

to reda : 
imho , you should use a database to perform this, especially if you request come from an apache server, this can be performed in 3 lines of php

i may assume that your "word" will then be associated with a result from your "indexer", with a db you can get all that into a single request

Comment: ofc, i understand, but the goal of using a hash table is to convert word to wordId very quicky knowing that it can be millions of words, millions isn't easy to search in a database.

Comment: if you mean find one result in a table of millions line, with correct index it is very fast, plus the hanlding of cache if millions search are performed